# JSONDecode Error on Python [Errno Expecting value] Retry later : 0/Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list, get

When I plug in the get request for a smaller subset of the data, it works fine. But the larger for loop I'm using seems to break the code somehow. Is the API limiting the amount of data I can take out? The loop works for a little bit until it suddenly crashes, every time I run it it crashes at a different point. I'd rather not have to make 30 dataframes and merge them all instead of just creating one from this loop.

Here's the code:

```
players_stats=[]

seasons=[1990,1991,1992,1993,1994,1995,1996,1997,1998,1999,2000,
       2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,
       2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021]

players_game_stats_url="https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/season_averages?"
print("Retrieving Player Ids")
print("-"*20)

for season in seasons:
    for player_id in players_ids:
        try:
            player_game_stats=requests.get(players_game_stats_url, params={"season":season,"player_ids[]":player_id}).json()
            player_average_pts=player_game_stats['data'][0]['pts']
            player_avg_assists=player_game_stats['data'][0]['ast']
            player_avg_blocks=player_game_stats['data'][0]['blk']
            player_avg_defrebounds=player_game_stats['data'][0]['dreb']
            player_avg_offrebounds=player_game_stats['data'][0]['reb']
            player_avg_3pt_attempts=player_game_stats['data'][0]['fg3a']
            player_avg_3pt_made=player_game_stats['data'][0]['fg3m']
            player_avg_2pt_attempts=player_game_stats['data'][0]['fga']
            player_avg_2pt_made=player_game_stats['data'][0]['fgm']
            player_avg_ft_attempts=player_game_stats['data'][0]['fta']
            player_avg_ft_made=player_game_stats['data'][0]['ftm']
            player_avg_steals=player_game_stats['data'][0]['stl']
            player_avg_mins=player_game_stats['data'][0]['min']
            player_avg_turnovers=player_game_stats['data'][0]['turnover']
            
            players_stats.append({"Player ID": player_id,"Season":season,"Average Points": player_average_pts,
                                  "Average Assists": player_avg_assists, "Average Blocks":player_avg_blocks, 
                                  "Average Defensive Rebounds":player_avg_defrebounds, 
                                  "Average Offensive Rebounds":player_avg_offrebounds, 
                                  "Average 3PT Attempts":player_avg_3pt_attempts,
                                 "Average 3PT Made":player_avg_3pt_made, "Average 2PT Attempts":player_avg_2pt_made,
                                  "Average 2PT Made":player_avg_2pt_made,
                                 "Average Free Throw Attempts":player_avg_ft_attempts, 
                                  "Average Free Throws Made":player_avg_ft_made, "Average Steals per Game":player_avg_steals,
                                 "Average Mins per Game":player_avg_mins,"Average Turn Overs per Game":player_avg_turnovers })

        except (IndexError):
            print(f"The stats for player:{player_id} were not found for season:{season}")
            pass
        
players_stats
```

A simpler version of it, which only includes one year (season=1990), works fine and gives the desired output:

```
Retrieving Player Ids
--------------------
The stats for player:671 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:735 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:847 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:907 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:957 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1037 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1089 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1179 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1247 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1281 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1368 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1445 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:237 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:220 were not found for 1990
The stats for player:1593 were not found for 1990
[{'Player ID': 2895,
  'Average Points': 18.43,
  'Average Assists': 2.2,
  'Average Blocks': 1.34,
  'Average Defensive Rebounds': 6.62,
  'Average Offensive Rebounds': 10.26,
  'Average 3PT Attempts': 0.51,
  'Average 3PT Made': 0.18,
  'Average 2PT Attempts': 6.95,
  'Average 2PT Made': 6.95,
  'Average Free Throw Attempts': 5.97,
  'Average Free Throws Made': 4.36,
  'Average Steals per Game': 0.96,
  'Average Mins per Game': '35:09',
  'Average Turn Overs per Game': 2.93}]
```

But the code that loops through all of the years ends up like this inevitably:

```
Retrieving Player Ids
--------------------
The stats for player:671 were not found for season:1990
The stats for player:735 were not found for season:1990
The stats for player:847 were not found for season:1990
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:910, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    909 try:
--> 910     return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
    911 except JSONDecodeError as e:
    912     # Catch JSON-related errors and raise as requests.JSONDecodeError
    913     # This aliases json.JSONDecodeError and simplejson.JSONDecodeError

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py:346, in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    343 if (cls is None and object_hook is None and
    344         parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    345         parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 346     return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    347 if cls is None:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:337, in JSONDecoder.decode(self, s, _w)
    333 """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
    334 containing a JSON document).
    335 
    336 """
--> 337 obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
    338 end = _w(s, end).end()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py:355, in JSONDecoder.raw_decode(self, s, idx)
    354 except StopIteration as err:
--> 355     raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
    356 return obj, end

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [8], in <cell line: 11>()
     12 for player_id in players_ids:
     13     try:
---> 14         player_game_stats=requests.get(players_game_stats_url, params={"season":season,"player_ids[]":player_id}).json()
     15         player_average_pts=player_game_stats['data'][0]['pts']
     16         player_avg_assists=player_game_stats['data'][0]['ast']

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:917, in Response.json(self, **kwargs)
    915     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.message)
    916 else:
--> 917     raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)

JSONDecodeError: [Errno Expecting value] Retry later
: 0
```

As you can see it only gets to a few loops before producing an error code. Any advice for an amateur python user?

Answer (score 0):

The API server was throttling my code. Adding a sleep function to it helped overcome that issue. import time + sleep function for the win!